# Send file to Google Drive from CLI to specific folder using public API key

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm trying to send test file to specific folder in my Google Drive account from CLI PHP script by using the **public API key**. I've generated the key and set my IP address in the Google dev console.

This is where i'm currently:

```
<?php
if (strtolower(PHP_SAPI) !== 'cli')
{
  throw new Exception("Run this from CLI only");
}

$autoloader_path = '.' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$autoloader_file = realpath($autoloader_path . 'autoload.php');

if (!file_exists($autoloader_file))
{
  throw new Exception("Autoloader file not found");
}

require_once $autoloader_file;

if (!class_exists('\Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader', true))
{
  throw new Exception("Composer autoloader failed to load");
}


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey('my-public-api-key');

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile($client);

$d = array(
  'data' => file_get_contents("test.txt"),
  'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
  'uploadType' => 'media'
);


$result = $service->files->insert($file, $d);

var_dump($result);
```

I'm getting "Login required" error:

```
$ php backup.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media&key=**<my key>**: (401) Login Required' in /home/raspi/gdrive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:79
Stack trace:
#0 /home/raspi/gdrive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(44): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#1 /home/raspi/gdrive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(556): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 /home/raspi/gdrive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(195): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#3 /home/raspi/gdrive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Drive.php(1760): Google_Service_Resource->call('insert', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
#4 /home/raspi/gdrive/backup.php(37): Google_Service_Drive_Files_Resource->insert(Object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile), Array)
#5 {main}
  thr in /home/raspi/gdrive/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 79
```

So how I can use the **Public API key** to send files or do I need to use OAuth? I've googled but only found OAuth file send examples.

`composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "raspi/gdrive",
  "description": "Gdrive",
  "license": "BSD",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access or make any changes to your Drive account without authenticating through OAuth 2.0. OAuth will only grant your application permission to access and update your account. More information of the OAuth process can be found in this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-php

For an example into sending your file, if it is stored in your computer, then you would rely on the 'insert' method of the 'Files' Resource, under the Drive API. Use the parents[] property to specify the id of the folder you want to save the item into. Check this link for an example in php: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Finally, if you want to move your file within your drive account, you will have to use the 'copy' method of the same resource (Files). You will have to provide the item id as parameter to copy the item, as well as providing the parentId of the folder you will create a copy into. This is the reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy